# How to create a conditional trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite, triggers

I have a table with an id as auto incremented primary key and another id.

```
CREATE TABLE tester (
"id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
"refId" integer DEFAULT 0
);
```

**refId** should be able to either be 0 (the default) or reference **id** if refId > 0 (i.e. act as foreign key).

Now I need two constraints:

> 1. A row should only be deletable if its **id** is not used (referenced?) by any other row's **refId**
> 2. A row should only be deletable if its **refId** is 0.

From what I have understood, I need to create a trigger that checks for these constraints before a DELETE event happens. And depending on **refId**'s value either abort the delete action or allow it.

However, I have a hard time understanding the syntax for this and how to do a conditional check. But what I have so far (in mind!) is concerning 1.):

```
CREATE TRIGGER no_delete_if_inuse
BEFORE DELETE ON tester
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'cannot delete because of foreign key violation')
    WHERE  (SELECT "refId" FROM tester WHERE "refId" = OLD."id") IS NOT NULL;        
END;
```

And concerning 2.)

```
CREATE TRIGGER no_delete_if_ref
BEFORE DELETE ON tester
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF OLD."refId" > 0 THEN RAISE(ABORT, "cannot delete tester because it refers to an existing tester");
END;
```

Does this make sense and is valid?
I am totally not sure, to me it does but well, I am all noob.

Also as a last question, can I alternatively combine this into a single trigger? For example would this be a valid query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER no_delete_if_inuse
    BEFORE DELETE ON tester
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'cannot delete because of foreign key violation')
        WHERE  (SELECT "refId" FROM tester WHERE ("refId" = OLD."id" OR "refId" > 0) ) IS NOT NULL;        
    END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a foreign key referring to the same table. Use `null` instead of `0` for rows without a reference:

```
create table tester(
    id int primary key, 
    refid int references tester,
    check (id <> refid)
);

insert into tester values
(1, null),
(2, null),
(3, 1),
(4, 3);
```

You need a trigger to ensure that a row which references another one cannot be deleted.

```
create or replace function before_delete_on_tester()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    if old.refid is not null then
        raise exception 
            'Cannot delete: (id)=(%) references (id)=(%)', old.id, old.refid;
    end if;
    return old;
end $$;

create trigger before_delete_on_tester
before delete on tester
for row execute procedure before_delete_on_tester();
```

Test:

```
delete from tester where id = 1;

ERROR:  update or delete on table "tester" violates foreign key constraint "tester_refid_fkey" on table "tester"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "tester".  

delete from tester where id = 4;

ERROR:  Cannot delete from tester. (id)=(4) references (id)=(3)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function before_delete_on_tester() line 4 at RAISE
```

In Postgres you have to define a trigger function. Read more:

- [Overview of Trigger Behavior](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/trigger-definition.html)
- [Trigger Procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)
- [Create Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was quite helpful but it would have been perfect if it had information about how I can incorporate my SELECT statements in the trigger function (the documentation was not helpful at all on this because there are no hints in there either, only simple conditional IF..ELSE IF and alike) and how combinations might look like. This took me a while to grasp. But as this is the only answer and it WAS pretty helpful to get the basic understanding I give it a "correct" :) Cheers